.NET 8 Facebook Authentication in Web API Challenge Exception - Redirect After Challenge?
Context:
Im Developing a WEB API in .NET 8 with Facebook Authentication using .net 8 identity core
Desired Behavior:
I need the api to expose a Get endpoint and start Facebook Authentication flow when the endpoint is hit.
Problem

When i do a Get Request on my browser to the given route i get an "An
InvalidOperationException is thrown stating the response has already
started when attempting to set a redirect header after calling
Challenge().".
That Exeption happens just after the challenge is answered by the user but before the Facebook App redirects to my callback Route.
Ive tryed to debug step by step to confirm this.
Ive tryed several callback routes in my Facebook App

Conclusion
I dont know if this is the flow expected for a .NET API, but it seemed to have issues setting my response. Thanks For your time, ive been looking for this on the web and i dont seemed to find an answer.
Program.cs
using emps.DTO;
using emps.Models;
using emps.Repository;
using emps.Services;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Cookies;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.Facebook;
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Identity;
using Microsoft.EntityFrameworkCore;
using Microsoft.Extensions.Options;
using Microsoft.OpenApi.Models;
using Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Filters;

var builder = WebApplication.CreateBuilder(args);

// CORS CONFIGURATION
builder.Configuration.AddJsonFile("appsettings.json", optional: false, reloadOnChange: true);
builder.Services.AddCors(options => {
    options.AddPolicy("debug", cors => {
        cors.AllowAnyMethod();
        cors.AllowCredentials();
        cors.AllowAnyHeader();
        cors.WithOrigins("https://localhost:3000");

    });
});
builder.Services.Configure<AppSettings>(builder.Configuration.GetSection(""));
builder.Services.AddControllers();
// Learn more about configuring Swagger/OpenAPI at https://aka.ms/aspnetcore/swashbuckle
builder.Services.AddEndpointsApiExplorer();

//IDENTITY CONFIGURATION
builder.Services.Configure<IdentityOptions>(options =>
{
    options.User.RequireUniqueEmail = true;
    options.Password.RequireNonAlphanumeric = false;
    options.Lockout.AllowedForNewUsers = true;
    options.Lockout.DefaultLockoutTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(5);
    options.Lockout.MaxFailedAccessAttempts = 5;
});

builder.Services.AddAuthentication(options =>{
    options.DefaultScheme = CookieAuthenticationDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
    options.DefaultChallengeScheme = FacebookDefaults.AuthenticationScheme;
}).AddFacebook(options => {
    options.AppId = builder.Configuration["appId"] ?? "";
    options.AppSecret = builder.Configuration["appSecret"] ?? "";
    options.CallbackPath = "/api/Auth/cb";
    options.Scope.Add("pages_manage_engagement");
    options.Scope.Add("pages_manage_posts");
    options.Scope.Add("pages_read_engagement");
    options.Scope.Add("publish_video");
    options.Scope.Add("public_profile");
    options.Scope.Add("email");
    options.Fields.Add("email");
    options.Fields.Add("name");
});
//COOKIE CONFIGURATION
builder.Services.ConfigureApplicationCookie(options => {
    options.Cookie.Name = "mytoken";
    options.Cookie.HttpOnly = true;
    options.ExpireTimeSpan = TimeSpan.FromMinutes(30);
    options.SlidingExpiration = true;
    options.Cookie.SecurePolicy = CookieSecurePolicy.Always;
    options.Cookie.SameSite = SameSiteMode.Lax;
});

builder.Services.AddIdentityApiEndpoints<User>().AddEntityFrameworkStores<IdentityContext>();
//SWAGGER Configuration

builder.Services.AddSwaggerGen(options =>
{
    options.AddSecurityDefinition("oauth2", new OpenApiSecurityScheme
    {
        In = ParameterLocation.Header,
        Name = "Authorization",
        Type = SecuritySchemeType.ApiKey

    });
    options.OperationFilter<SecurityRequirementsOperationFilter>();


});
// DB Context
builder.Services.AddDbContext<IdentityContext>(options => {
    options.UseSqlServer(builder.Configuration.GetConnectionString("defaultConnection"));
});



//Repositorios

builder.Services.AddScoped<PostRepository>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UsersRepository>();
//Servicios
builder.Services.AddScoped<PostService>();
builder.Services.AddScoped<UsersService>();
//builder.Services.AddHttpClient();
builder.Services.AddScoped<FacebookService>();
builder.Services.AddAuthorization();
var app = builder.Build();

// Configure the HTTP request pipeline.
if (app.Environment.IsDevelopment())
{
    app.UseSwagger();
    app.UseSwaggerUI();
}
app.UseHttpsRedirection();
app.MapIdentityApi<User>();

app.UseCors((options) => {
    options.AllowAnyHeader();
    options.AllowCredentials();
    options.AllowAnyMethod();
    options.AllowAnyHeader();
    options.SetIsOriginAllowedToAllowWildcardSubdomains();
    options.WithOrigins(["https://localhost:3000", "https://web.facebook.com"]);
});
app.UseAuthentication();
app.UseAuthorization();


app.MapControllers();

app.Run();


Controller Routes
        public async Task< IActionResult> FacebookLogin() {
            var properties = this.SignInManager.ConfigureExternalAuthenticationProperties("Facebook", null);
            properties.RedirectUri = Url.Action("FacebookCb", "Auth");
            return Challenge(properties,"Facebook");
                          
        }
        [HttpGet("cb")]
        public async Task<IActionResult> FacebookCb(string code)
        {
            
                Console.WriteLine(code);
                var response = await this.SignInManager.GetExternalLoginInfoAsync();
                if (response != null)
                {
                    var email = response.Principal.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Email);
                    var username = response.Principal.FindFirst(x => x.Type == ClaimTypes.Name);
                    if (email != null && username != null)
                    {
                        User userData = new User { Email = email.Value, UserName = username.Value };
                        await SignInManager.SignInAsync(userData, true);
                        var myUser = await this._service.GetUser(email.Value);
                        if (myUser != null)
                        {
                            if (response != null && response.AuthenticationTokens != null)
                            {
                                var token = response.AuthenticationTokens.FirstOrDefault(e => e.Name == "access_token");
                            }
                        }

                    }
                }
                return NoContent();
            
        }


System.InvalidOperationException: StatusCode cannot be set because the response has already started.
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ThrowResponseAlreadyStartedException(String value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.set_StatusCode(Int32 value)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Http.DefaultHttpResponse.Redirect(String location, Boolean permanent)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.RemoteAuthenticationHandler`1.HandleRequestAsync()
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Authentication.AuthenticationMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.SwaggerUI.SwaggerUIMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext)
   at Swashbuckle.AspNetCore.Swagger.SwaggerMiddleware.Invoke(HttpContext httpContext, ISwaggerProvider swaggerProvider)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Diagnostics.DeveloperExceptionPageMiddlewareImpl.Invoke(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.WebTools.BrowserLink.Net.BrowserLinkMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Watch.BrowserRefresh.BrowserRefreshMiddleware.InvokeAsync(HttpContext context)
   at Microsoft.AspNetCore.Server.Kestrel.Core.Internal.Http.HttpProtocol.ProcessRequests[TContext](IHttpApplication`1 application)


Thanks For your time I hope my question is clear enoght
